# What to do when kpss contradicts ADF?

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, macroeconomics, kpss-test

I'm testing to see if Inflation has a unit root and if it has a drift and trend, just drift or no drift and trend. My results from the ADF test looks like this:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
Augmented Dickey--Fuller test
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
type:   trend  drift  none
AR1:    0.86   0.86   1 
lags:   12     12     12 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

     statistic  1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3     -1.67 -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
phi3      1.42  8.73  6.49  5.47
tau2     -1.68 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58
phi1      1.55  6.70  4.71  3.86
tau1     -0.07 -2.60 -1.95 -1.61
```

tau3, tau2 and tau1 tests the null of unit root -- none can be rejected at the 5% level.
phi3 checks for drift and trend, if the critical value is **over** the 5pct, inflation has a drift and trend. phi1 check for only drift. My conclusion for this test is that inflation has a unit root (it's not stationary) and there is no drift or trend.

Next I test Inflation with a kpss test (ur.kpss in the urca package). The results look like this:

```
####################### 
# KPSS Unit Root Test # 
####################### 

Test is of type: mu with 3 lags. 

Value of test-statistic is: 0.2485 

Critical value for a significance level of: 
                10pct  5pct 2.5pct  1pct
critical values 0.347 0.463  0.574 0.739
```

If the test statistic is below the critical value: inflation is stationary. So the kpss shows that inflation is stationary (in conflict with the ADF test!).

My sample size is only 72 (18 years, quarterly data). As I understand it, there is a big risk of making a mistake with the ADF test if n is small (I think n < 500). Maybe this is why the results are different.

**3 questions**:

1. Should I keep the data as-is, since kpss says inflation is stationary (the alternative being that I take the first difference)?
2. I actually have the inflation data as monthly data. The reason why I'm using quarterly data is that another variable only exists as quarterly data and booth series need to be of the same interval. Is it possible to do the tests on inflation as monthly data and then aggregate inflation to quarterly data only afterward?
3. Can I still trust that the ADF.test is right on the data is without drift and trend?

Finally, here's a plot of the data.

[image]

Let me know if you want me to clarify anything or if I should supply code as well.

**EDIT:** Clarification: Question one relates to the order of integration. My interpretation is that kpss says that the data is integrated of **order zero**. Can I trust this to be true? If I go by ADF.test, I should difference the data...

Comment: What are the chances that inflation is not reverting to some long-term mean? I.e. that it may wander off and never come back to somewhere around 2% or perhaps 5%? I would say, quite low. So chances that inflation has a unit root are quite low. This is what the graph also suggests.

Comment: Hi @Tomas. Keep an eye on the number of lags while conducting your tests. The inclusion of 12 lags in an ADF is unconventional. As a first rule of thumb with quarterly data, you should be running the ADF with 4 lags (i.e., a year as oppossed to three years). Check this again, and see if it affects your results.